# Is the asymptotic density of positive integers $n$ satisfying $\gcd(n, \sigma(n^2))=\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))$ equal to zero?

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors-multiples

(This post is an offshoot of this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3629818).)

Let $\sigma(x)$ denote the sum of divisors of $x$.  (https://oeis.org/A000203)

**QUESTION**

> Is the asymptotic density of positive integers $n$ satisfying $\gcd(n, \sigma(n^2))=\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))$ equal to zero?

I tried searching for examples and counterexamples to the equation
$$\gcd(n, \sigma(n^2))=\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))$$
via [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/), it gave me this output for the following **Pari-GP** script:

```
for(x=1, 100, if(gcd(x,sigma(x^2))==gcd(x^2,sigma(x^2)),print(x)))
```

> All positive integers from $1$ to $100$ (except for the integer $99$) satisfy $\gcd(n, \sigma(n^2))=\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))$.

Generalizing the first (counter)example of $99$ is trivial.

If ${3^2}\cdot{11} \parallel n$, then $11 \parallel \gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))$  and  $11^2 \parallel \gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$.  So the asymptotic density in question is less than
$$1-\frac{2}{3^3}\cdot\frac{10}{11^2} = \frac{3247}{3267} \approx 0.993878.$$

Also, if $3 \parallel n$, then with probability $1$ there exist two distinct primes $y$ and $z$ congruent to $1$ modulo $3$ such that $y \parallel n$ and $z \parallel n$.  In this case, we get $3 \parallel \gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))$  and  $3^2 \parallel \gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$.  So the asymptotic density in question is less than
$$1-\frac{2}{3^2} = \frac{7}{9} \approx 0.\overline{777}.$$

The real open problem is whether the asymptotic density is $0$.

Comment: For what it's worth, $\sigma(n^2)$ is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A065764

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the density does go to zero, but quite slowly. If $p \equiv 1 \bmod 6$ is prime then there are two solutions $0<r<s<p-1$ of $$x^2+x+1=0 \bmod p$$

If $p\parallel n$ then, with probability $1,$ there are two distinct primes $x $ and $ y,$  each congruent to $r \bmod p,$ with $x \parallel n$ and $y \parallel n.$ ( Either or both could be congruent to $s$ as well.)

Then $p \parallel \gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))$ while $p^2 \parallel \gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)).$ So the asymptotic density for this not to happen is $1-\frac{p-1}{p^2}<1-\frac{1}{p+2}$

If we can argue that the chance that none of these events happen is asymptotically $\prod(1-\frac{p-1}{p^2})$ over the primes congruent to $1 \bmod 6,$ then that asymptotic density is $0.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @AaronMeyerowitz.  Assuming
$$1 - \frac{p-1}{p^2} < 1 - \frac{1}{p-1}$$
is correct, then we obtain
$$\frac{1}{p-1} < \frac{p-1}{p^2}$$
which implies that
$$p^2 < (p-1)^2 = p^2 - 2p + 1$$
resulting in the contradiction
$$p < \frac{1}{2}.$$
Hence, I am led to conclude that there must be a typo in your upper bound for
$$1 - \frac{p-1}{p^2}.$$

Comment: OK, I fixed it. Though I hadn't used it. The idea was, roughly $1-\frac{1}{p}$